# Ignore optimistic-locking

Tags: java, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I've got the entity that contains @version field.
Sometimes I need to update it in spite of optimistic locking exception.

Can I turn it off somehow in that case? Or I should just reload entity and retry to save it n times until it updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work directly agains the connection:

`org.hibernate.Session.doWork(Work work)`.

But   you are incurring in last write wins. It is better to use transactions isolation levels to perform row lock. But the database must  support      them.

`Hibernate 3.x` has the `Session.connection()` but in `4` it is gone.

Comment: In my situation sometimes I need first write wins, and sometimes I need last write wins. What the right way to make "Session.doWork" if I work with Hibernate through service and dao classes? I dont want to change my dao and write special methods for directly conections, is that only one solution?